# php array_intersect and array_intersect_assoc function for associate array showing error

Tags: php, arrays

I m trying to get the common value present in this two array as is below, I tried method array_intersect as well

Array 1:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [gcr_id] => 210
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [gcr_id] => 219
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [gcr_id] => 271
        )

)
```

Array 2 :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [gcr_id] => 220
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [gcr_id] => 270
        )

)
```

i m using `array_intersect_assoc($arr1,$arr2)`

it showing following error

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: newapi/Arena.php

Line Number: 255

Backtrace:

File: /home/kodwell/public_html/avinash_workspace/hoyo_new/application/controllers/newapi/Arena.php
Line: 255
Function: array_intersect_assoc
```

and it showing output as well along with error

or any alternative way to get such structure common data , thanks in advance

Comment: Those funtions do not work in a recursive manner, that means the _values_ are compared, here an attempt to convert them into strings is done to make them comparable. Your arrays have a structure that cannot be compared by those functions.

Comment: any way to compare it and get common data?

Comment: Sure, instead of `array-intersect-assoc(...)` use `array-intersect-uassoc(...)`. That one allows you to specify a compare function where you yourself can implement how the values of the outer arrays should get defined instead of relying on a php-builtin mechanism to do so.